# Get footer row cell values of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview with two textboxes in the footer. What's required is get the textbox values, store it to a datatable and then bind the same to the gridview. 
I am unable to get the textbox values. They show up empty (as you can see). Where am I going wrong.

[image]

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
ShowFooter="true" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"  
OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">           
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit">
</asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" 
CommandName="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
   &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"  
   CommandName="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
   </EditItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.No">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <%#Container.DataItemIndex %>
     </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
       <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lbId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'>
     </asp:TextBox>
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNewId" 
     SetFocusOnError="true"
    ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NAME">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lbName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("name") %>'>
     </asp:TextBox>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
     <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
      ControlToValidate="txtNewName" SetFocusOnError="true" 
      ErrorMessage="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
     </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" 
      CommandName="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <FooterTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" 
       CommandName="Insert" ></asp:LinkButton>                    
     </FooterTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

CS:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Insert":
                GridViewRow fRow = gv.FooterRow;
                dt.Columns.Add("id");
                dt.Columns.Add("name");
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["students"];
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["id"] = ((TextBox)fRow.FindControl("txtNewId")).Text;
                dr["name"] = ((TextBox)fRow.FindControl("txtNewName")).Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                ViewState["students"] = dt;
                gv.DataSource = ViewState["students"];
                gv.DataBind();
                break;
        }
    }
```

The textboxes are txtNewId, txtNewName.

Comment: Please show the GridView markup

Comment: use this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24085/Insert-Update-Delete-with-Gridview-Simple-Way

Comment: If any of the below answers was what you were looking forward, you must mark that as answer. This can help others who come across this question to quickly identify the best answer

Comment: So... what about that bounty?

Comment: Thank you everyone. Unfortunately, none of the solutions worked. I have updated the question with the ASPX code. Also, why should I not use a link button but a button instead?

Comment: I didn't know if (GridViewRow)((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer); would work. But it appears it does. Also, this question has changed considerably. You weren't able to get the footer row, now the question is new rows?

Comment: The Question remains the same. I am unable to get the values from the footer row textboxes. After Clicking 'Insert', the values dont show up in the row, as shown in pic. Thanks for your time though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the button click event, use the following to get the actual GridViewRow of the footerL

```
protected void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // This is the crux - 
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((sender as Button).NamingContainer);
    // ...
    // then you can get your textboxes
    // Since we know it's an insert
    dt.Columns.Add("id");
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    dt = (DataTable)Session["students"];
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    TextBox txtnewid = (TextBox) row.FindControl("txtNewId");
    TextBox txtnewName =  (TextBox) row.FindControl("txtNewName");
    dr["id"] =  txtnewid.Text;
    dr["name"] = txtnewName.Text ;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    Session["students"] = dt;
    gv.DataSource = dt;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

**EDIT**
The reason viewstate didn't work is because the viewstate lasts only between postbacks. Sessions stay alive for the duration of the user's session. The default is 20 minutes of idle time.

You would normally use ViewState for persisting data between pages during a postback.

This doesn't address best practice, it's just what it is.

Comment: There is no error, but on clicking the button, it adds an empty row

Comment: This part is just a paste of **your** code. The point was you were not getting the footer row, now you are. If you are getting an empty row, that suggest you aren't populating your text boxes. I guess awarding the bounty is easier said than done.

Comment: Oh, and don't store your data table in the viewstate for this sort of thing. Store it in the session.

Comment: @reckface...THANK You very much. It worked with Session. Could you plz tell me why is this so.Was it because I had some configuration for session in web.config. Thank you again

Answer (score 6):

Do not use grid_Row command for insert. Use button click event

like this. It will solve your problem

```
protected void OnCmdInsertClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Grid's footer row
    var footerRow = gv.FooterRow;
    if(footerRow !=null)
    {
        //get your textbox instances
        var txtNewId = (TextBox) footerRow.FindControl("txtNewId");
        var txtNewName = (TextBox) footerRow.FindControl("txtNewName");
        // Check for null
        if(txtNewId !=null && txtNewName !=null)
        {
            var dt = (DataTable)ViewState["students"];
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["id"] =  txtNewId.Text;
            dr["name"] = txtNewName.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);                
            ViewState["students"] = dt;
            gv.DataSource = ViewState["students"];
            gv.DataBind();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check whether you are binding the grid view correctly in the Page Load. What i mean to say is whether you are binding with in the if condidtion

```
       if(!IspostBack)
{

  BindGridView();
}
```

I hope this helps. Check it out..

Comment: Yes the function is within the if block

Answer (score 3):

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   if (e.CommandName.Equals("Insert"))
             {
                GridViewRow fRow = gv.FooterRow;
                dt.Columns.Add("id");
                dt.Columns.Add("name");
                dt = (DataTable)ViewState["students"];
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                TextBox txtnewid = (TextBox) fRow.FindControl("txtNewId");
                TextBox txtnewName =  (TextBox) fRow.FindControl("txtNewName");
                dr["id"] =  txtnewid.Text;
                dr["name"] = txtnewName.Text ;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                ViewState["students"] = dt;
                gv.DataSource = ViewState["students"];
                gv.DataBind();
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

To bind the footer with data, use the below code

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
         TextBox txtNewId = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtNewId");
         txtNewId.Text = "New 01";
    }
}
```

...and to retrieve value from the footer textbox,

```
TextBox txtNewId = (TextBox)gvGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNewId");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This,

```
TextBox txtName = GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("yourtextboxId") as TextBox;
string name = txtName.Text;
```

Or

```
GridViewRow row = ((GridView)sender).FooterRow;
TextBox txtName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("yourtextboxId");
if (txtName == null)
{
    return;
}
string name = txtName.Text;
```

Comment: Tried both the solutions. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the best way to get the value is using:

```
((TextBox)<grid_name>.FooterRow.FindControl("<textBox_id>")).Text
```

I hope this helps.